# Typescript Context not read in Next.js

Tags: typescript, next.js, material-ui

I get a custom error when i shouldn't. A custom context isn't read.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ehkpG.png)

I was trying to put some custom error notifications within my form, but the custom context i created for that doesn't works. And a custom error is thrown cause "it doesn't exists". I am coding with next js and typescript.

```
    "use client"
import React, { useContext } from 'react'
import { Notification } from "../components/Notification"
import { AlertColor } from '@mui/material';

type ContextProperties = {
    getError: (msg: string) => void,
}



export const NotificationProvider: React.FC<{ children: JSX.Element }> = ({ children }) => {

    //Con estos tres modificamos los estados del tipo de componente Notification.
    const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);
    const [message, setMessage] = React.useState('');
    const [severity, setSeverity] = React.useState<AlertColor | undefined>(undefined);

    //Se maneja por fuera del return, si fuera ahi dentro seria dentro de la aplicación y no queremos eso.
    //maneja cuando quiero cerrar la notificación.
    const handleClose = () => {
        setOpen(false);
    }

    const getError = (msg: string) => {

        setSeverity("error");
        setOpen(true);
        setMessage(msg);

    }

    const value = {
        getError
    }

    //.provider es una propiedad del creador de context de react. Lo que estamos creando es un proveedor.
    //para ello necesitamos crear un contexto, que nos permite llamar el atributo/clase provider, que permite inyectarlo en toda la aplicacion.

    //El componente notification no engloba nada está al mismo nivel que el children.
    return (
        <NotificationContext.Provider value={value}>
            <Notification handleClose={handleClose} open={open} severity={severity} message={message} />
            {children}
        </NotificationContext.Provider>
    )
}

const NotificationContext = React.createContext<ContextProperties | null>(null);

export const useNotification = () => {
    const context = useContext(NotificationContext);
    if (!context) throw new Error('Context doesn\'t exists')
    return context
}
```

And here is my ussage of the context.

```
"use client"

import { Button, Container, Grid } from '@mui/material'
import Typography from '@mui/material/Typography'
import Image from "next/image"
import Link from 'next/link'

import { useNotification } from './context/notification.context'


export default function Home() {


  const { getError } = useNotification();

  const handleClick = () => {
    getError('Hello world');
  }

  return (
    <>
      <Container component="main" maxWidth="lg" >

        <Grid
          container
          alignItems="center"
          justifyContent="center"
          direction="column"
          sx={{ minHeight: "90vh" }}
          spacing={5}
        >
          <Grid item>
            <Image
              className="border-slate pb-8"
              src="/images/AppLogo.png"
              width={300}
              height={300}
              alt="AppLogo"
              priority={true} />
          </Grid>

          <Grid item>
            <Typography variant='h1'>Welcome to SharpSight</Typography>
          </Grid>

          <Grid item >
            <Typography variant="h4" fontWeight="light">A web application for price comparison</Typography>
          </Grid>

          <Grid item >
            <Link href="/register">
              <Button variant="contained" type="button">Get Started</Button>
            </Link>
          </Grid>

          <Grid item>
            <Button variant='contained' type="button" onClick={handleClick}>Notification Test</Button>
          </Grid>
        </Grid>

      </Container>
    </>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

your setup seems correct. the only thing, you probably did now wrap your app with the `NotificationProvider`. since you have `use client`, you are using `next.js 13`. in top level `layout.tsx`

```
export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode
}) {
  return (
    <html lang='en'>
      <body>
        <NotificationProvider>{children}</NotificationProvider>
      </body>
    </html>
  )
}
```

Comment: Thanks i figured it out after 10 hours. I am a beginer with this.